# set hover for a div class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html that looks like this:

```
 <div class="optionClass">Option 1</div>
 <div class="optionClass">Option 2</div>
 <div class="optionClass">Option 3</div>
```

What I am attempting to do is have the background-color a user defined color, and at the same time have the div background-color change on hover. Because the color is user defined, I am unable to use css to control the background color or hover behavior. Hoping to find some javascript that can be applied to the div specific to "optionClass"

I have found the jQuery code, but it applies to all divs. Is there a way to make it apply to a specific class?

```
$('div').hover(
           function () {
              $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
           }, 
            
           function () {
              $(this).css({"background-color":"blue"});
           }
        );
```

Comment: `$('div.optionClass')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the class name in the jQuery selector.

```js
$('div.optionClass').hover(
  function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "red"
    });
  },

  function() {
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
  }
);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Option X</div>
<div class="optionClass">Option 1</div>
<div class="optionClass">Option 2</div>
<div class="optionClass">Option 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ or [jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) lets you pass in a selector to select the elements you want to have this apply to. You can write a selector, just like you would for CSS, and use it in your call, i.e. `$('.my-class').hover(...)`.